# When double-clicking a number in VS Code, is it possible to have it ignore the unit? (ignore "px" in "12px")

Tags: visual-studio-code

When double-clicking a number:
100%: selects "100" (good)
100px: selects "100px" (bad)

To more rapidly change number values, it would be great if VS Code could ignore units of measure when double-clicking a number like it does with symbols.

This seems like a feature that would be part of *Editor: Word Separators*, but it looks like you can only add single characters to the list.

Does anyone know if it's possible to change this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#select-by-with-surround) you can specify with an regular expression what you consider a "word" and with a keybinding you are faster than using the mouse in selecting.

Use the `surround` property, see the link.